# TypeScript: Limiting the key of an object with a specific string by using interface

Tags: typescript

I want to limit the key of an object with interface.

I can achieve this by using `type`

```js
type KeyOfObj = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

type Type = { [key in KeyOfObj]?: string };

const objWithType: Type = {
  a: 'a', // valid
  b: 'b', // valid
  c: 'c', // valid
  d: 'd', // invalid
};
```

Is there a way to achieve the above behavior using `interface`?
In other words, is there a way to make code below valid?

```
type KeyOfObj = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

interface Interface {
  [key in KeyOfObj]?: string; // this code throws error
}

const objWithInterface: Interface = {
  a: 'a', // valid
  b: 'b', // valid
  c: 'c', // valid
  d: 'd', // invalid
};
```

I am still confused about when to use `type` vs `interface` for object even after reading this (https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/interface-vs-type-alias-in-typescript-2-7-2a8f1777af4c) article.

I always thought `interface` could do more than what `type` could do in terms of object. However, for the case above, it seems like `type` can do more compared to what interface can do. Any advice?

-- Question Summary --

1. How to make the second block of code valid while achieving what the first block of code is doing?
2. Any advice when to use `type` vs `interface` dealing with object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type aliases and interfaces are different in subtle ways that are hard to list out exhaustively.  I tend to think of interfaces as being easier to *use* but harder to *define* than type aliases.  Since you're trying to define an interface, let's look at the rules for defining them.

[Type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) can give a name to just about any type, and as such are very flexible in how you're allowed to define them.  The type `{[key in KeyOfObj]?: string}` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  That's a type, so you can give it a name via type alias:

```
type Type = { [key in KeyOfObj]?: string };
```

[Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) can only be defined by explicitly writing out key/value pairs and by using `extends` to extend named types whose property keys are known statically.  A mapped type using the `{[A in B]: C}` syntax cannot be used *directly* as the definition of an interface, since it is neither an explicitly written-out list of key/value pairs, nor is it a named type.

But, you do have a type named `Type`, and when you inspect it, you see that the compiler knows that its keys are `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`:

```
/* type Type = {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
    c?: string | undefined;
} */
```

Thus the type `Type` is a valid target for `extends`, and you can define your interface like this:

```
interface Interface extends Type {} // okay
```

So while the mapped type in question cannot be used *directly* in an interface definition, it can be used *indirectly* by being given a name.

This works as you wanted:

```
const objWithInterface: Interface = {
  a: "a", // valid
  b: "b", // valid
  c: "c", // valid
  d: "d" // invalid
};
```

Do note that you can't *always* use this trick; it depends on whether or not the type you're extending has statically known keys.  Here's a way it can fail:

```
type TypeWithUnknownKeys = { a: string, b: string } | { c: string };

interface InterfaceFailure extends TypeWithUnknownKeys {}; // error!
//                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// An interface can only extend an object type (or 
// intersection of object types) with statically known members.
```

This fails because a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) doesn't have statically known keys.  The type in question will either have an `a` key and a `b` key *or* a `c` key, but the compiler can't think of this as a single object type to extend.  So even though it has a name, you can't use it to build an interface.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmCBGArKBeKAiAhrlAD56pGm4DGuA3AFD2iRQAq40OA3lANoDW8KAEsAdrHjI06ALoB+AFxQAzsABOYgOZQAvgwD0AKijNo7Ft3pRrUfIpXqtJKAFdRAEwhIxEdwxtQqPaqGqLapG6e3qK+-jZUwY5hzpFePn70OlCG+oxiwBBqSPhU0ACSogVFJdAQAB4FHspsHFBcOoxUAPaiqlBdGADqwsAAFhVVxaVKE4VTnG1WtkoEuAA0UPr6UABu+AA2wu5LqCvkG1u7B0dLVCs0F9t7h8fW7ivuRJdizzd6jKYWpBhmMAKqifiiLoAd1EcBAzW4ywcoU0G1OKKcWVIPDumOS-3o+TmNSgs2qpQAYvhhPsXGpag0IE0gRAQaNwZCYXD4M12rRNttCmoumoAIT0S4BaUy2Vy6wAPyVypVqpVku2AEFxMSKdAqPhxD19iAoPVGu5bEaMBAqMATK0ABSiqAakSVQrKW3AYQ9fpIfo2u0OyDKACUUGhI1GDnwPoN+xNUC5sKgAFsIGnUJ6AHSMIA)

Comment: Yes, this is the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you for such a clear explanation! jcalz